# Using linked xaml file in VS2010 project for resuing of xaml

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, xaml

I linked xaml files in vs2010 solution for resuabiltiy like this:

[image]

And I tried to load that by resource dictionary tag in App.xaml like this:

```
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

    <ResourceDictionary Source="/Myproject;component/CommonStyles/Button.xaml" />

...

</ResourceDictionary>
```

But it can't loading in project.

How can I load these xaml files?

edited:

1. I tried that.
2. But compiler still can't find out xaml files.
3. So I trans a build working time from 'Page' to 'Resource'.
4. and then, a lot of compile error occured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case these xaml files resides in different assembly, you need to import them using pack syntax like this -

```
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
<ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Myproject;component/CommonStyles/Button.xaml" />
......
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```

Comment: Can you post one of the xaml files here that how you define it?

Comment: I solved it. 'Add as links' have lot of problem. so I decided to make a new wpf library dll. thanks.